# What is the font used for the word Komplete?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What is the font used for the word Komplete in these images.

Most of their logos are done using popular fonts like Trade Gothic etc, but it's been hard to find one with a K, M and P like that.

https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ was of little help, so were other font identification services such as fontsquirrel's matcherator. I've also posted on their forums.

Any help will be grately appriciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Did you try browsing Dafont's Sans serif category?

Comment: You will find it using [Identifont "Fonts by Appearance"](http://www.identifont.com/index.html), inserting your set of letters and answering the questions.

Comment: Looks inspired from Konnect Bold (or vice versa)

Comment: I won't be surprised if it's 'not' a font actually. Could be created specially for the title, since it's name of some product.

Comment: Montserrat or Gotham are the closest that I can think of

Comment: This resembles question "I am going to launch a series of brown sugar drinks. To print the bottle labels and cans I want to know what is this font: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdSUY.png and where I can download it from."

Answer (score 0):

A bit late I guess but that's the Graphik font.